# How can I test @onFailure method?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, addcallback

How could I go to "@Override public void onFailure(Throwable ex) { ... }"?

It always go "@Override public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, KafkaPresponseDto> result) {...}.

I want to print
log.error("Unable to send message=["+kafkaPgResponseDto.toString()+"] due to : " + ex.getMessage());

Please help...

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, KafkaPgResponseDto>> future = pgResponseKafkaTemplate.send(kurlyTopicNamePgResponse, kafkaPgResponseDto);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, KafkaPgResponseDto>>(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, KafkaPgResponseDto> result) {
                KafkaPgResponseDto kafkaPgResponseDto = result.getProducerRecord().value();
                log.debug("Send message=["+kafkaPgResponseDto.toString()+"] with offset=["+result.getRecordMetadata().offset()+"]");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                log.error("Unable to send message=["+kafkaPgResponseDto.toString()+"] due to : "+ex.getMessage());
                kafkaTransactionService.failedProcessingKafkaHistorySave(orderNo, kurlyTopicNamePgResponse, gson.toJson(payload), ex.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no need in the real Kafka to test your functionality. Consider to use a `MockProducer` for injection into that `KafkaTemplate` and emulate an error for that `onFailure()` case: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-mockproducer